# Translate by .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, translate

I would like translate my site by .htaccess, but my script does not work.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/en$ http://www.google.com/translate_c?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R,NC]
```

Have you an idea to solve this problem or a simpler solution?

(Excuse me, I'm a French who has a very bad english ;) )

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Instead of just giving the code. Provide what you need it to do.

Comment: I want to automatically translate the site over the browser language of the visitor.

If it detects that the browser is English, it return to the page google translate http://www.google.com/translate_c?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://www.website.tdl/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Give it a try this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ en [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^en$ http://www.google.com/translate_c?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: After testing, I had a redirect to http://www.website.tdl/kunden/homepages/25/dxxxxxxxxxxx/htdocs/en (1and1 hosting). 

I tested with this code:
`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^en$ http://www.google.com/translate_c?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,NC]`

and it works !

Thanks